# GreenDao select a single column?

Tags: android, greendao

I need to return only a single column using GreenDao. This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT NAME FROM PERSON
```

How can I do it using GreenDao?

Comment: Did you manage to accomplish this? If yes, could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 0):

Well greenDao does provide access to the underlying database if you want to perform raw queries (DaoSession.getDatabase) - which you may feel in this case would be more efficient than the greenDao alternative - which would involve getting all Persons and iterating over the results to extract the name (easily done with personDao.loadAll()). The idea in using an [ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) library would be to use Person objects, and access the name attribute on it. e.g. person.getName().

Comment: This is why I use a simple fromCursor method now instead of greenDao. This allows me to specify the projection I'm interested in.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> rawQuery(final String query) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBHelper.getDaoSession().getDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        retList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                list = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    list.add(cursor.getString(i));
                }
                retList.add(list);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        return retList;

    }
```

Use this kudos let me know you want something more ?

Comment: Well the problem with this kind of query is that i can't ensure that only one thread at a time is using my SQLiteDatabase